# How can I populate a calendar with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, cross-platform, tizen

I'm trying to develop an application where I need to use this calendar : http://fullcalendar.io/

The problem is that I can populate it manually, but I can't populate it from my Database.

This is the function that populates the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
        events:[
            {
                title: "aaaa",
                start: "2014-12-12"
            },
            {
                title: "bbb",
                start: "2014-12-13"
            }
        ]


    });



});
```

and this is the function that allows me to get my data from the Database:

```
function getEvents(db){

        db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM NOTES', [], function (tx, results) {
           // var allEvents = [];
           var allEvents=[]; 

            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
            //var event = {};
            allEvents.push({
                title: results.rows.item(i).note,
                start: results.rows.item(i).whenn

            });


            }


            $.each(allEvents, function(idx, obj){
                alert(obj.title);
                });
        }, null);

        });



    };
```

When i call the function getEvents(db) in events, it shows me the alerts but doesn't populate the calendar.

PS: I can't use php files.

Comment: you mean fill instead of full correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderEvent

```
.fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event [, stick ] )
```

which, as the name suggests, renders a new event on the calendar.

According to [the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/), event must be an Event Object with a title and start at the very least. Normally, the event will disappear once the calendar refetches its event sources (example: when prev/next is clicked). However, specifying stick as true will cause the event to be permanently fixed to the calendar.

For you, I guess this would translate to something like:

```
$.each(allEvents, function(idx, obj){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', obj);
});
```

I've not used fullCalendar, but if this doesn't work, make a fiddle of what you've got and I'll make you a working example.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating your problem?